# How do I construct a new centrality measure?

Tags: r, graph, graph-algorithm, igraph

I want to construct a new centrality measure using `igraph`, preferably in `R`.

How would I begin this?

For example, would I be better adding to the `igraph C library` or the `R interface`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really boils down to what your comfortable level.  That said, igraph is a primarily a C library (you can [browse all the source code on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/igraph/)), so the most logical way to extend it is probably in C.  For instance, the closeness function in R just call the related C function:

```
> closeness
function (graph, v = V(graph), mode = c("all", "out", "in")) 
{
    if (!is.igraph(graph)) {
        stop("Not a graph object")
    }
    mode <- igraph.match.arg(mode)
    mode <- switch(mode, out = 1, `in` = 2, all = 3)
    on.exit(.Call("R_igraph_finalizer", PACKAGE = "igraph"))
    .Call("R_igraph_closeness", graph, as.igraph.vs(v), as.numeric(mode), 
        PACKAGE = "igraph")
}
```

Here is [the existing centrality sourcecode](http://igraph.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzr/igraph/0.6-main/annotate/head%3A/src/centrality.c).